# Universal solution to save more than 5 MB data offline, which support all Browsers and PhoneGap application?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I developed a game in web technology that store the data in LocalStorage. But it is giving DOM Quota Exceed Error after Local Storage is getting full. I am looking for a universal solution which supports all browsers and PhoneGap application. I can not use FileAPI because IE and safari does not support it. Not IndexDB because, Safari doesn't support IndexedDB. Not Sqlite because, Firefox and IE does not support it. Please help.

Comment: Are you compressing the data?

Answer (score 0):

According to this safari does partially support IndexedDB: http://caniuse.com/#search=indexed

Anyway, if it doesn't suite your needs, why not use different storages depending on the browser? You can use IndexedDB in all but Safari, and use WebSQL in Safari :-). You can use something like this to polyfill it without impact: http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/